# Differences in discrete distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

Suppose I have two vectors, `a` and `b`, each with the following counts per unique value:

```
# key: value = value: count
a_counts = {
    0: 250,
    1: 300,
    2: 20
}

b_counts = {
    0: 275,
    1: 250,
    2: 150
}
```

At a glance, sample `b` (which has the potential to contain many of the same individuals from sample `a`, but also may not), looks to be pretty similar to `a` in terms of the number of 0s and 1s. However, sample `b` has *way* more 2s than `a`.

What kinds of statistical tests could I use to test whether sample `b` is different from `a`? My gut tells me to take the proportion of each value in each sample and do some sort of t-test, but I'm not entirely sure... Perhaps chi-square is more appropriate?

Comment: It depends.  Are the samples each the result of a set of independent observations from very large populations (or processes)?  If so, the textbook answer is to apply a chi-squared test (search our site or Google it).  Otherwise, please provide details of how these samples were obtained.

Comment: I have a population of roughly 2 million individuals and some categorical variable `x` associated with each person. My goal is to take an initial snapshot of the distribution of this variable for the individual population, and compare subsequent instances/points of observation against this original distribution. So, record metadata for those folks at time *t*, record metadata again at time *t* +1, and compare the latter with the former. It is not guaranteed that every individual observed at *t* will also be observed at *t*+1, but the across-period coverage should be very high.